# split the text by comma and append rows pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe a like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','102','103','104'],             
                  'Text':["""{"y":["8","8 plus"]""","""{"x":["7"]}""","""{"x":["7","7+","7++"]}""","""{"x":["7"]}"""]})
```

wanted output:

[image]

i have tried this one how to extract only those exact values

```
df2 = df.set_index('User').Text .str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: Is that dict or just string ?

Comment: its string only

Comment: Is the first string correct? I think is missing a "}".

Answer (score 1):

May be this:

```
import ast
df[['Text1','Text2']]=df.pop('Text').str.split(":",expand=True)
df.Text2=df.Text2.replace("}","",regex=True).apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.Text1=df.Text1.replace("\W",'',regex=True)

s=pd.DataFrame({'B':np.concatenate(df.Text2.values)},index=df.index.repeat(df.Text2.str.len()))
df.join(s).drop('Text2',1).rename(columns={'B':'Text2'})
```

***Output***

```
  User Text1   Text2
0  101     y       8
0  101     y  8 plus
1  102     x       7
2  103     x       7
2  103     x      7+
2  103     x     7++
3  104     x       7
```

Comment: Thanks but the code is. It dynamic. Suppose we have 3 or 4 values.it will throw error. It only works 2 vlaues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first dictionary is missing the closing bracket (`}`). You could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['101', '102', '103', '104'],
                   'Text': ["""{"y":["8","8 plus"]}""", """{"x":["7"]}""", """{"x":["7","7+","7++"]}""",
                            """{"x":["7"]}"""]})

# convert to dictionary and drop the text column
dictionaries = df.assign(D=df.Text.apply(ast.literal_eval)).drop('Text', axis=1)

# convert each row to multiple ones (given by the values of each dictionary)
tuples = [(u, k, v) for u, r in dictionaries.values for k, vs in r.items() for v in vs]

result = pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=['User', 'Text1', 'Text2'])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  User Text1   Text2
0  101     y       8
1  101     y  8 plus
2  102     x       7
3  103     x       7
4  103     x      7+
5  103     x     7++
6  104     x       7
```

Comment: Thanks but it's a string not dictionary.

Comment: @KumarAK Is a string representing a dictionary right?